# Jquery hide DIV on input focus, destroyed by window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an overlay div that fades in on scroll and out on scroll up. Works fine. My users gets annoyed by this div when entering text in forms, it sometimes hides the send button.
Therefor I try to hide it with JS when input on focus. Works like a charm on desktop but fails bigtime on mobile due to the fact that the keyboard, when popping up, also moves the content. It therefor triggers the scroll event making the visible again.

I wonder how that can be solved in the neatest of ways, any example from my snippet below?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop()>800){
        $('.symo').fadeIn()
    }else{
        $('.symo').fadeOut()
    }
});
$('form').delegate(':input', 'focus', function() {
    $('.symo').hide();
})
.delegate(':input', 'blur', function() {
    $('.symo').show();
});
```

Comment: you can .off scroll event when focus, .on when blur.. Or check for focus input inside scroll event

Comment: `.delegate`? What version of jQuery do you use?

Comment: Good point @bigless!

Comment: 3.2.1 @qwertiy, works like a charm ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet, got rid of the delegate stuff as well.

Thanks!

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop()>800 && !$("input,textarea").is(":focus")){
        $('.symo').fadeIn()
    }else{
        $('.symo').fadeOut()
    }
});
```

Comment: `$("input,textarea").is(":focus")` or simpler `$(":input").is(":focus")`. Also, use `.stop()` to prevent animation buildups: `$('.symo').stop().fadeIn()`.